# Checking user input for String

Tags: java, string, input

How do I check to make sure that the input by user is a string only?

```
System.out.println("What kind of crust would you like?");
     crust = scan.next();
     while( !crust.equals(scan.hasNext())) <===(PROBLEM, THIS DOES NOT WORK)
      {
         System.out.println("Pick a valid choice.");
         crust = scan.next
```

Comment: crust is already a String no need to check for it

Comment: `!crust.equals(scan.hasNext()))` ??????? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Guys, read the question. 3 comments make no sense or are bad solutions. `Scanner#next` **returns** a `String`. No `instanceof` needed.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner will be reading in a string with the `.next()` method. The next token will be automatically read in a treated as string. If you were to enter in something like 123 when your program asks for the crust, the crust variable will hold the string "123" not the number 123.

Your while loop doesn't work because the `.hasNext()` function returns a boolean, while crust is always a string.

If you want to make sure that "crust" has no numeric characters, either use regex or, more simply, loop through each character of the string and check if the character is numeric or not

```
boolean containsNumber = false;
for (int i = 0; i < crust.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(crust.charAt(i))) {
        containsNumber = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

The containsNumber boolean would then be true if the string contains a number, and false if it does not contain a number.

Comment: You will have to restructure your code to deal with the containsNumber boolean. Try adding my code as a separate function which returns a boolean, and then add an if statement to check whether or not the "crust" string contains numeric values.